# Two date range return

Tags: php, wordpress, date

How to return the two date combine string like below.

```
Start Date : 11/2/2020
End Date : 26/2/2020
```

Then Output should be like this : 11 to 26 feb 2020

```
Start Date : 26/2/2020
End Date : 5/3/2020
```

Then Output should be like this : 26 feb to 5 march 2020

```
Start Date : 29/12/2020
End Date : 2/1/2021
```

Then Output should be like this : 29 Dec 2020 to 2 Jan 2021

Please Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a nice problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Sorry, I can not thinking this type of logic.

Comment: You need to start by looking at all three components of the date separately - day, month, and year. If the year is the same, then you will only have to output it once - otherwise, each output value needs to be the complete date. If the year is the same, then perform the same check on the month, and output the appropriate parts.

Comment: Here is your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60039218/12232340 if you are english then use first solution in answer, if not english then use second solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow :-)

PHP has a native [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class which allows you to perform date manipulations and date-formatting.

In your specific case you could start to convert your two dates into objects and then [reformat](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) it into your expected format.

Here is an example:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $startString);
```

With this in mind we can now create a function which will check your requirements and return the string on your custom format.

```
function my_date_range(DateTime $start, DateTime $end)
{
    $sameYear = $start->format('Y') === $end->format('Y');
    $sameMonth = $sameYear && $start->format('m') === $end->format('m');
    $sameDay = $sameMonth && $start->format('d') === $end->format('d');

    if ($sameDay) {
        return $start->format('d M Y');
    }
    if ($sameMonth) {
        return sprintf('%s to %s', $start->format('d'), $end->format('d M Y'));
    }
    if ($sameYear) {
        return sprintf('%s to %s', $start->format('d M'), $end->format('d M Y'));
    }

    return sprintf("%s to %s", $start->format('d M Y'), $end->format('d M Y'));
}
```

Below you'll find my example dates and usage:

```
var_dump(
    my_date_range(DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '11/2/2020'), DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '26/2/2020')),
    my_date_range(DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '26/2/2020'), DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '5/3/2020')),
    my_date_range(DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '29/12/2020'), DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '2/1/2021')),
    my_date_range(DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '2/1/2021'), DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '2/1/2021')),
)
```

Result:

```
string(17) "11 to 26 Feb 2020"
string(21) "26 Feb to 05 Mar 2020"
string(26) "29 Dec 2020 to 02 Jan 2021"
string(11) "02 Jan 2021"
```

Comment: That does not take part of leaving out the “repeating” parts that are the same for both dates. You would just get `11 feb 2020 to 26 feb 2020` for the first example here, and that is not what was asked for.

Comment: @CBroe oh wow. Thank you for the hint. You are totally right. I will adopt my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

- put your date parts into arrays - `['11', 'Feb', '2020']`
- loop over them in reverse order, from year to day
- unset each entry in your start date array, that has the same value as the corresponding entry in your end date array - for as long as the current part matches; break out of the loop once the first mismatch occurs
- join the parts that are left back together

```
function time_range_format($start, $end) {
  for($i=2; $i>=0; --$i) {
    if($end[$i] == $start[$i]) {
      unset($start[$i]);
    }
    else {
      break; // important to leave the loop, once the first non-matching part is encountered
    }
  }
  return ($start ? implode(' ', $start) . ' to ' : '') . implode(' ', $end);
}

var_dump(
  time_range_format(['11', 'Feb', '2020'], ['26', 'Feb', '2020']),
  time_range_format(['26', 'Feb', '2020'], ['5', 'Mar', '2020']),
  time_range_format(['29', 'Dec', '2020'], ['2', 'Jan', '2021']),
  time_range_format(['29', 'Dec', '2020'], ['29', 'Dec', '2020'])
);
```

Results for above examples:

```
11 to 26 Feb 2020
26 Feb to 5 Mar 2020
29 Dec 2020 to 2 Jan 2021
29 Dec 2020
```

By checking if $start still contains anything at the end, and only putting out the `to` if it does, you can even handle the “edge case” that start and end date are the same, as in the very last row of this example.